# Presto query: add the average value as a new column

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have the following `wage_table`:

```
worker_id, hourly_rate
  1      , 20
  2      , Null
  3      , 30
  4      , 40
```

I want to add an additional column `mean_hourly_rate` like:

```
worker_id, hourly_rate, mean_hourly_rate
  1      , 20         ,  30
  2      , Null       ,  30
  3      , 30         ,  30
  4      , 40         ,  30
```

I have the following code, but got error **'column worker_id not in GROUP BY clause'**

```
SELECT
    *,
    AVG(hourly_rate) AS mean_hourly_rate
FROM wage_table
```

I am wondering what's the correct way of doing it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [window function](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#aggregate-functions): `avg(hourly_rate) OVER ()`

For example:

```sql
WITH data(worker_id, hourly_rate) AS (
    VALUES
        (1, 20),
        (2, Null),
        (3, 30),
        (4, 40)
)
SELECT 
    worker_id, 
    hourly_rate, 
    avg(hourly_rate) OVER () AS mean_hourly_rate
FROM data
```

produces:

```
 worker_id | hourly_rate | mean_hourly_rate
-----------+-------------+------------------
         1 |          20 |             30.0
         2 |        NULL |             30.0
         3 |          30 |             30.0
         4 |          40 |             30.0
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use cross join

```
 SELECT
    T1.*, T2. mean_hourly_rate
 FROM wage_table T1
 CROSS JOIN (select AVG(hourly_rate) AS mean_hourly_rate from wage_table
Where hourly_rate is NOT NULL) T2;
```

Here is a db fiddle link - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8c819f2e1e040c74c0f0514e271a4c84

Comment: Thanks @Somy I want to ignore null rows and do average. Does this ignore the null rows?

Comment: @Edamame - Thanks for clarifying. Edited the answer to address the same. It should work now.